# Create index only (no column values) for new dataframe/series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I am fairly new to Python and Pandas and I have not found an answer to this question while searching.

I have multiple csv data files that all contain a date-time column and corresponding data. I wanted to create a series/dataframe that contains a specific span of dates (all data is 1 min interval, so if I wanted to look at July for example I would set the index to start at July and go until the end).

Can I create a series or dataframe that contains only the date-time intervals as an index and does not contain column info? Or would I create an index (the row numbers) and then fill my column with the dates.

I also am unsure of using 'pd.merge' vs 'newdataframe = pd.merge'. When using just pd.merge, nothing comes up in my variable explorer (I use Anaconda's Spyder IDE), only when I use newdataframe = pd.merge does it appear.

Thanks in advance,